# Codename One Parse Json

Tags: json, parsing, codenameone

I can't seem to figure out how to parse this `Json` in `Codename One`:

```
{
  "ParsedResults": [
    {
      "TextOverlay": {
        "Lines": [],
        "HasOverlay": false,
        "Message": "Text overlay is not provided as it is not requested"
      },
      "FileParseExitCode": 1,
      "ParsedText": "REPORT 1 - STUDENT INFORMATION SERIES \r\n50 SOMEWHERE SCHOOL DISTRICT COUNTY SCHOOLS \r\n1234 SOMEWHERE SCHOOL \r\nDATE: 01/01/0001 \r\nCLASS ROLE \r\nBLDG-RM \r\n01-111 \r\nPGM \r\n101 \r\nMINS \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n090 \r\n10 \r\nFM \r\n2 \r\nMINS \r\n090 \r\nPGRM \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n101 \r\n11 \r\nFW \r\n3 \r\nTEACHER \r\n100 SMITH, C \r\nDATES \r\nCOURSE SEC/M \r\n1000111 \r\nDAYS \r\nMTWRF \r\nSTUDENT NAME \r\nADOE, AYANA \r\nBEDOE, BROOKE \r\nTITLE \r\nSOC ST \r\nTIMES \r\nSCHL \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n4207 \r\n08 \r\nFH \r\n3 \r\nT \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n3 \r\n09 \r\no \r\n0900 1100 080117 060118 \r\nSTDT NBR \r\n123456789 \r\n234567891 \r\n345678912 \r\n456789123 \r\n567891234 \r\n678912345 \r\n789123456 \r\n891234567 \r\n912345678 \r\n012345678 \r\n123456780 \r\n234567801 \r\n345678012 \r\n456780123 \r\n567801234 \r\n678012345 \r\n780123456 \r\n801234567 \r\n123321123 \r\n234432234 \r\n456654456 \r\n567765567 \r\n678876678 \r\n789987789 \r\n890098890 \r\n901109901 \r\nSR \r\nFM \r\nFW \r\nMB \r\nMM \r\nMH \r\nFW \r\nMA \r\nFW \r\nMl \r\nMW \r\nFM \r\nMB \r\nMH \r\nMB \r\nFM \r\nMM \r\nMB \r\nMM \r\n06 \r\n2 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n05 \r\n07 \r\n2 \r\nCODOE, CHRISTOPHER \r\nDOE, DEREK \r\nEDOE, EDWARD \r\nFEDOE, FERLICIA \r\nGODOE, GINA \r\nHEDEO, HENRY \r\nINDEO, INDIA \r\nJADOE, JERRELL \r\nKIDOE, KARL \r\nLADOE, LYSHA \r\nMEDOE, MADAIYCA \r\nNIDOE, NEPHTALIE \r\nOODOE, OLIVIA \r\nPELDOE, PATRICK \r\nQUODOE, QUINTAN \r\nRUDOE, RACHEL \r\nSTADOE, STEPHAN \r\nTEEDOE, TERRELL \r\nUEDOE, UMMI \r\nVEDOE, VALERIA \r\nWADOE, WAHEED \r\nXADOE, XIE QIAN \r\nYIDOE, YADLEY \r\nZIADOE, ZANDER \r\n03 \r\nMl \r\n1 \r\nOK \r\nMA \r\n1 \r\n01 \r\nMB \r\n4 \r\n02 \r\nMH \r\n2 \r\n04 \r\nMM \r\n2 \r\n05 \r\n26 \r\nMW \r\n2 \r\n",
      "ErrorMessage": "",
      "ErrorDetails": ""
    }
  ],
  "OCRExitCode": 1,
  "IsErroredOnProcessing": false,
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "ErrorDetails": null,
  "ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds": "8550"
}
```

I want the `ParsedText` portion. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not since the JSON parsing in Codename One is different

Comment: @cricket_007 please re-read the question/answer and reopen it. You will notice that the answer is **different** from the one that's "supposedly" a duplicate.

Comment: @tushar see comment above

Answer (score 0):

With the `JSONParser` this should be something like:

```
JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
Map<String, Object> m = p.parseJSON(myReader);

List l = (List)m.get("ParsedResults");
Map<String, Object> r1 = (Map<String, Object>)l.get(0);
String parsedText = (String)r1.get("ParsedText");
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with this, but its giving me an error on this line of code: 

Map<String, Object> r1 = (Map<String, Object>)l.get(0);

error: cannot find symbol symbol:   method get(int)

Comment: Why raw `List`?

Comment: You can use a list of `Map` but since you will need a cast anyway I'd rather go with raw which isn't as verbose

Answer (score 0):

Had to make it an ArrayList, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

```
JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
Map<String, Object> m = p.parseJSON(myReader);

ArrayList l = (ArrayList)m.get("ParsedResults");
Map<String, Object> r1 = (Map<String, Object>)l.get(0);
String parsedText = (String)r1.get("ParsedText");
```